# CypressIO tests to be executed in multiple URL

Tags: automation, e-commerce, cypress, base-url

An Ecommerce website have different URL's for different countries. And each of these website have to be tested. We have set of automation scripts written in CYPRESSIO. Looking for ideas how these scripts can be rerun for different URL's.

Example URL's for different countries

1. ```
   UK: https://www.abc.co.uk
   ```
2. ```
   CH: https://www.abc.ch
   ```
3. ```
   DE: https://www.abc.de
   ```

There are some functionalities which are country specific and hence we have to run tests for all the URL's . Any ideas and leads would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set the tests inside a data loop

```
const urls = ['https://www.abc.co.uk', 'https://www.abc.ch', 'https://www.abc.de'];

urls.forEach(url => {

  describe(`Testing url: ${url}`, () => {

    before(Cypress.config('baseUrl', url))

    it('...', () => {

    })

})
```

---

Testing a simplified scenario,

**support/index.js**

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  console.log('beforeEach in support', Cypress.config('baseUrl'))
})
```

**dynamic-baseUrl.spec.js**

```
const urls = ['https://www.abc.co.uk', 'https://www.abc.ch', 'https://www.abc.de'];

urls.forEach(url => {

  describe(`Testing url: ${url}`, () => {

    before(() => Cypress.config('baseUrl', url))

    it('sees the required baseURL', () => {
      console.log('it', Cypress.config('baseUrl'))
    })

  })
})
```

**console output**

```
beforeEach in support https://www.abc.co.uk
it https://www.abc.co.uk

beforeEach in support https://www.abc.ch
it https://www.abc.ch

beforeEach in support https://www.abc.de
it https://www.abc.de
```

**Cypress log**

```
Testing url: https://www.abc.co.uk
...passed

Testing url: https://www.abc.ch
...passed

Testing url: https://www.abc.de
...passed
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried implementing this solution. forEach() is picking only the last URL from the list, is there any classic mistake i am doing?

I also have a beforeEach() method defined in index;js file which helps me login to our local test environment. [Attached pics in the initial query above]

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Need to wrap the setting of baseUrl so that is executes on the queue instead of synchronously in the test.

Comment: Thank you, this works for my situation :)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create country-specific `cypress.json` files.

For eg. cypress-de.json

Inside it you can define `baseURL` and country-specific test cases using `testFiles[]` as:

```
{
  "testFiles": [
    "TC_01.spec.js",
    "TC_02.spec.js",
    "TC_03.spec.js",
    "TC_04.spec.js"
  ],
  "baseUrl": "https://www.abc.de"
}
```

Now when you want to run tests, all you have to do is pass the relevant cypress.json file through CLI using the command:

```
npx cypress run --config-file cypress-de.json
```

Comment: Hi @Alapan Das, I tried with different cypress.json files. However, i see that scripts fail showing timeout issue.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the timeout errors that you're getting ?